# KendoUI and Angular2 autocomplete with data from remote (live search)

Tags: angular, autocomplete, kendo-ui-angular2

On the documentation site for [Data Binding](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/data-binding/) there are some examples on how to get the datasource from a remote server. However, in all these scripts, it loads the entire list on init and uses that list to filter.

I am connecting to a webservice for searching for cities around the world. For obvious reasons, I don't want to load the entire list of cities beforehand but search on type.
I have no idea how to do so with this component, and haven't found anything helpful so far.

Does anyone know how to solve this, or can anyone point me in the right direction (tutorials, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [filterChange event](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/autocomplete/filtering/) with filterable=true, and load your data source from there. In the initial load, if required, you can may be bind that listItems array to few default values, then load data on filter change.